# Results in Firebug console.log are truncated

Tags: javascript, firebug

If you try to make console.log of a very long array, firebug console shows you just a part of the full result.

Example:

```
    arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],["casa","auto"],["casa","auto","casa","auto","casa","auto","casa","auto","casa","auto","casa","auto","casa","auto","casa","auto",[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]]

    console.log(arr); // .... ["casa", "auto"], ["casa", "auto", "casa", 17 more...]]
```

In this case, it shows the first part of the array and then the word  `17 more...]]`

How can I show all the array result?

I would like to make copy and past. Unfortunately console.dir returns an javascript object browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`console.dir(arr);` will show the whole array.

Comment: element number 61 also shows 17 more.. Is it valid answer ? console.dir is an javascript object browser.

Comment: I would like to make copy and past. Unfortunately console.dir returns an javascript object browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you just want to see the results.  You can loop through the array and write out each array item.

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```